# On Finish activity in Android

Tags: android, android-activity, sdk

Im trying to integrate Tapresearch survey in my android app. The company provides an SDK. The SDK gives the ability to use events listeners. One of the listeners doesn't work which is onSurveyModalClosed()` where normally the app resumes running. All other listeners works fine except this one. 
When Tapresearch open surveys it runs this activity : com.tapr.internal.activities.survey.SurveyActivity .

Is there any way check if this activity has been finished without using the listener `onSurveyModalClosed()` ?

Comment: Can I see your code ? Like where you have put this - onSurveyModalClosed() ??

Comment: @AsutoshPanda here is sdk documentation. I copied the code from here > https://www.tapresearch.com/docs/android-integration-guide

Comment: @Fat-Bee hey could you spare some of your time to tell me about this **Tapresearch survey**'s performance actually I'm thinking to integrate it to my app so your review would be helpful

Comment: @NikhilKumar When you start to integrate the **Tapresearch survey** you only have the ability to use test survey untill your app goes live in the store then they allow you to use real surveys. For now Im still using the test mode. You can download the demo app here and run it to see how it is https://github.com/TapResearch/Android-Integration-Demo . Just you need to register in the **Tapresearch survey**'s website to get TAPRESEARCH_API_TOKEN and USER_IDENTIFIER which is the GAID of your test device.

Comment: @Fat-Bee thanks a lot for your time and great answer . Okay I'll check this by the way is it more efficient than advertisement services

Comment: Depends on What you are using it for. For me I am using to courage users to gain extra points by taking surveys.

Comment: @Fat-Bee hey could you please tell me how to get api token

Comment: @NikhilKumar After you register in their website, go to Apps, then create a new app after that go back to apps list and click on settings button you find in the right and you will the API key

Comment: @Fat-Bee thanks a lot again for your great help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your question, "is there any way check if this activity has been finished without using the listener", yes there is a way.

Just put a Log message in both the methods. And see which Log message is printed in the console or which is printed first and take actions accordingly.

```
@Override
public void onSurveyModalClosed() {
   //Survey isn't visible resume app
   Log.i("Sequence_of_execution", "SurveyModalClosed");
}

@Override
protected void onStop() {
   super.onStop();
   // Your code goes here
   Log.i("Sequence_of_execution", "ActivityStopped");
}
```

I guess onSurveyModalClosed() is called when you manually close the survey by taking any action and not when the Activity stops.

And for your question in comments to check if you are coming from SurveyActivity to MainActivity, do this since you don't have control over SurveyActivity-

1. Declare a shared preferences variable called "SurveyActivityStarted" in MainActivity and set it to false.
2. When starting the SurveyActivity from MainActivity, set "SurveyActivityStarted" to true.
3. on onResume of the MainActivity check if "SurveyActivityStarted" is true, if its true its coming from SurveyActivity.
4. Reinitialise "SurveyActivityStarted" to false in the MainActivity for future use cases.

Comment: Thank you for explaining. Yes I aware of this but how can I implement it with this issue?

Comment: Try to apply my updated answer and tell me what Log messages you get in the console.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. the only message that printed is "ActivityStopped". I was thinking if there is a way to check if OnResume happens from this activity com.tapr.internal.activities.survey.SurveyActivity ?

Comment: So if OnResume in Mainactivity happens from this activity com.tapr.internal.activities.survey.SurveyActivity then i will do the rest

Comment: Their website lacks good documentation, I guess onSurveyModalClosed() is called when you manually close the survey by taking any action and not when the Activity stops. You can actually raise a ticket to ask them when onSurveyModalClosed() is called.

Comment: Yes thats true. But when i put a Toast text and i run onSurveyModalOpened() the toast text shows up. Anywayis there anyway to tell the app if the resume happens from this activity com.tapr.internal.activities.survey.SurveyActivity ?

Comment: You can check if the Activity has resumed or not on onResume() of the Activity. I don't see any method to check if the Survey modal has reopened or resumed. See the updated answer, hope it helps.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/167970/discussion-between-asutosh-panda-and-fat-bee).